# All accented charaters are turned into question marks

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-15

I have a file that has accented charaters: `ÇÍââÇÍ`

I need to change them into *ISO-8859-15* encoding

The code:

```
    String fileName = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/temp6893820181068878551.txt";

    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

    FileChannel ch = fin.getChannel();
    int size = (int) ch.size();
    MappedByteBuffer buf = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, size);

     byte[] utf8bytes = new byte[size];
    buf.get(utf8bytes);

    System.out.println(new String(utf8bytes));  

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

        Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15");

        String string = new String ( utf8bytes, utf8charset );
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        byte[] iso88591bytes = string.getBytes(iso88591charset);

        for ( byte b : iso88591bytes )
            System.out.printf("%02x ", b);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        String string2 = new String ( iso88591bytes, iso88591charset );

        System.out.println(string2);
```

But I get as output:

```
ÇÍââÇÍ


??????


3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 

??????
```

Comment: I dunno man.  It worked for me.  I can get bytes just like you did and they're not question marks.  Are you **SURE** your input file has what you think in it?

Comment: what do you get? not 3fs?

Comment: well it prints what it has in it, the first line in the output

Comment: I get for the bytes: `0x199 0x205 0x226 0x226 0x199 0x205` and then the characters print fine: ÇÍââÇÍ

Comment: nop I still get 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f   ??????

Comment: Something on your end.  You may have edited the source to make your example more clear, and removed the line causing the problem.  Check again carefully any lines you didn't show us.

Comment: are you sure you are reading them from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem was the file itself.

When writing to the original file, it must be in encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing the string before calling .getBytes() on it, i.e. call Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFC)

The same looking accented characters can be represented in different unicode binary forms. Perhaps only the NFC form can be converted to iso-8859-15?

Comment: Really? When I try this code:
String s = "ÇÍââÇÍ";
Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15");
byte[] bytes = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKC).getBytes(iso88591charset); for ( byte b : bytes )
    System.out.printf("%02x ", b);
 It prints the following: c7 cd e2 e2 c7 cd